# web.config conflict on IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

folder structure

```
docroot
  |- wordpress
     |- web.config 
     |- wp-content
        |- japi
           |- index.php
           \- web.config
     ...
  ...
```

As you can see there are 2 web.config s. One in the wordpress folder and one in wordpress/wp-content/japi folder.

**japi/web.config**

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Now when I request for http://domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/japi/test. The japi/web.config seems to be neglected and only wordpress/web.config is being considered.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I'm not sure why the japi config is being ignored, however you can follow some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882425/can-i-have-multiple-web-config-files-in-a-single-web-project) and take a look at [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides).

Comment: What is this file? If you're handling API requets in WordPress you should use the REST API or AJAX hooks.

Comment: How do you know it is being neglected? The sample looks exactly like the standard web.config for WordPress and if that's the case, the behavior will be exactly the same as the one in the project root. Can you please rephrase the question as Given x When y I Expect z But Instead See ___?

Answer (score 1):

I believe WP uses rewrites and routing through the website's main index.php file (web.config, .htaccess).  So, if you don't specify a specific file that you are accessing (i.e. mysite.com/subdir/test.php), then you aren't really playing in that sub-directory, your just following the core rewrite rules.

So - if you create a file called test.php inside of a directory called subdir, and you access it directly (as in mysite.com/subdir/test.php) then you should expect the proper web.config should be used; however, since you are not accessing a specific file directly, you are using the folder-structure/endpoint, which uses WP's routing functionality.  This may be the reason that the web.config file is being ignored and may be the answer to your question.